# Set of Possible Polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x^6\pm x^5\pm x^4 \pm x^3 \pm x^2 \pm x \pm 1 = p(x)$$

What is the set $A$ of possible polynomials from the class of polynomials $p(x)$ such that the polynomial only has real roots.

I am confused over how to approach the problem. Should I use Descarte's rule?

Answer (score 3):

Descartes' rule just gives informations on the number of positive/negative real roots.

[Newton's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_inequalities) are the key, here. Assuming that such a polynomial completely splits over $\mathbb{R}$, we must have:
$$ \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2 \geq \pm \frac{1}{\binom{6}{0}}\cdot\frac{1}{\binom{6}{2}} = \pm\frac{1}{15}$$
but that may happen only if the sign is negative. So we have that the coefficient of $x^6$ and the coefficient of $x^4$ have to be opposite. Can you fill the missing details?

Comment: Why splits over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @EugenCovaci: sorry, typo. now fixing.

Comment: It looks like a very good idea +1